# Python web scraping with requests and beautiful soup blocked by needing javascript

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter, scrape

I am trying to scrape text from a website. I use the simple code: requests.get(url_here). My code has worked until recently. Now, when I use requests, instead of getting the site's text, I get a message saying:

"The site requires JavaScript to be enabled! The browser you're using doesn't support JavaScript, or has JavaScript turned off."

I have verified that my browser does have javascript enabled. Is there a way around this?

Working in Python with a Jupyter notebook on a Mac, for reference.

Comment: You'll need something like Selenium which does javascript. The requests module does not execute javascript. Alternatively, you can try to find the AJAX call that the javascript makes and then replicate that AJAX call using requests. Share the URL if it's not confidential.

Comment: Using requests to access this webpage worked perfectly for months. As far as I can tell, nothing on the website has changed that would make requests no longer work. Does this information help any?

Comment: "The site requires JavaScript to be enabled! The browser you're using doesn't support JavaScript, or has JavaScript turned off." is a clue that something has changed even though the appearance may not have changed. Try opening the page in your browser with javascript turned off.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a small article that was written by me. It is a very basic web scraping of the BookMyShow website. I hope it will work for you.

[Introduction to Web Scraping](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/introduction-to-web-scraping-258d5f117357)